# No such column error: how to prevent this error if no item in db?

Tags: android, sql

Well I think my title says it... Using following code:

```
public int getCorrectAnswersPrev(int level, String player) {
        int count = 0;
        level = level - 1;
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANSWERS WHERE LEVEL =" + level
                        + " AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1 AND PLAYER=" + player, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        count = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        myDataBase.close();

        return count;

    }
```

Sometimes a player simply didn't answer certain questions, so it means that at the beginning of a level, there are no specific items there... I get this error, although I initialize count as 0, but I understand that it still executes the query and returns the error. But is there a way I could prevent this if there is no item in the db?

EDIT:

```
    11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Bog: , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANSWERS WHERE LEVEL =1 AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1 AND PLAYER=Bog
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at com.hup.game.db.DataBaseHelper.getCorrectAnswers(DataBaseHelper.java:251)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at com.hup.game.LevelSelectorAdapter.getView(LevelSelectorAdapter.java:75)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1432)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:935)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8319)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8319)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8319)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8319)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
11-16 13:34:30.188: E/AndroidRuntime(10206):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The issue is in the query.. please post the full error trace here so we can help you better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANSWERS WHERE LEVEL =1 AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1 AND PLAYER=Bog
```

throws an error.

It should be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANSWERS WHERE LEVEL =1 AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1 AND PLAYER='Bog'
```

Comment: Indeed this does the trick! Is it also wise to add the solution of Kalai Selvan and @Luis, or is this not necessary?

Comment: If that's required, you can add that too.

Comment: for string you have to use single quotes @MatthiasVanb

Comment: What about a risk of SQL injection?

Answer (score 3):

After concatenation value in `player` is treated probably as column name, so instead of:

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANSWERS WHERE LEVEL =" + level
    + " AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1 AND PLAYER=" + player, null);
```

try do it with parameters:

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANSWERS WHERE LEVEL = ? " +
    " AND ANSWERCORRECT = 1 AND PLAYER = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(level), player }
);
```

Comment: Hi michal, thanks, but I got it working with ' ' before and after my variable... :)

Comment: @MatthiasVanb yes, you can do it this way, but then it's vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Even if you are learning this already try to do it right way :-).

Comment: Ok, but I think this is mainly the case when I would be dealing with edittext fields? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MatthiasVanb in general, yes. In my opinion it's better to do even from the very beginning things right. Because there is a chance that you will not make such a thing in really important project (I'm not saying that this isn't), even in different programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no records, `Cursor` returns `null`.

You should test `c == null` before using `moveToFirst()` like this:

```
if(c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use "ifnull"
```

for eg:

```
  Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(select ifnull(max(tm.no),0) as serial_no "
                        + "from table_bun as tb inner join table_mar"
                        + " as tm on tb.id = tm.id "
                        + "where tb.bid = " + bId
                        + " and tb.sid =  " + SId
                        + " and tb.eby  = '" + UId + "'", null);
```